# how to solve Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation function for uuid() in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm creating store for adding data in redux store for that i used uuid() Function but it throws runtime Exception 'Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation'.

```
import {createStore,combineReducers} from 'redux';
import uuid from 'uuid';
//Add Expense
const addExpense = (
{description='',note='',amount=0, createdAt=0} ={}) =>({
type:'ADD_DETAIL',
expense: {
   id:uuid(),
    description,
    note,
    amount,
    createdAt
}
})
//Expenses Reducers
const detailDefaultState  = [];
const detailReducers = (state=detailDefaultState,action) =>{
switch(action.type){
    case  'ADD_DETAIL':
    return state.concat(action.expense)
    default:
        return state;
}
};

//Store Creation
const store = createStore(
combineReducers({
    expenses:detailReducers,       
})
);
store.subscribe(()=>{
console.log(store.getState());
})
store.dispatch(addExpense({description:'Rent',amount:100}));
```

if i remove uuid() function from code its run correct. 
version of uuid() is 3.2.0.

Answer (score 1):

You are not importing `uuid` correctly. You need to specify which type of `uuid` you want to use, e.g.

```
// v4 - random uuid
import uuid from 'uuid/v4';

uuid(); // ⇨ will produce something like '45db52e1-f95c-4b5f-99a2-8b8d978c99b4'
```

You can read more about the types here: https://github.com/kelektiv/node-uuid.

Comment: while deprecated, you can still use uuid.v4()
But I agree, your answer should be what's used on anything new.